# Oracle | Retrieval of records from tables having One to many relationship

Tags: oracle, join, group-by, inner-join, one-to-many

I have two tables which share one-to-many relationship. `MY_FACT` is the parent table whereas `MY_RMDETAILS` is the child table having multiple records for a single parent record.

**Table MY_FACT:**

| FACT_ID | FACT_DATE | TOTAL_DEMAND |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 21/04/2022 | 500 |
| 2000 | 21/04/2022 | 500 |

**Table MY_RMDETAILS:**

| RM_ID | FACT_ID | PROMISE_QTY | REQUEST_QTY | RM_ITEM_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | 1000 | 500 | 500 | RM1 |
| 201 | 1000 | 400 | 500 | RM2 |
| 202 | 1000 | 500 | 500 | RM3 |
| 203 | 1000 | 400 | 500 | RM4 |
| 300 | 2000 | 500 | 500 | RM1 |
| 301 | 2000 | 500 | 500 | RM2 |
| 302 | 2000 | 500 | 500 | RM3 |
| 303 | 2000 | 500 | 500 | RM4 |

I need to write a query to have below output.

**Logic:**

If `MY_RMDETAILS.PROMISE_QTY` is less than `MY_RMDETAILS.REQUEST_QTY`, the supply is insufficient.

So for any given `MY_FACT` record, if any one of its children records from `MY_RMDETAILS` has `PROMISE_QTY` less than `REQUEST_QTY`, the flag  `SUPPLY_SUFFICIENT` in output should be `N` else it should be `Y`.

And `INSUFFICIENT_RMs` column in output should show the `MY_RMDETAILS.RM_ITEM_NAME` of "insufficient" records as comma separated format.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

| FACT_ID | FACT_DATE | TOTAL_DEMAND | SUPPLY_SUFFICIENT? | INSUFFICIENT_RMs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 21/04/2022 | 500 | N | RM2,RM4 |
| 2000 | 21/04/2022 | 500 | Y |  |

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use subquery with condition aggregate function.

```
SELECT t2.*,
       CASE WHEN t1.INSUFFICIENT_cnt > 0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END,
       t1.INSUFFICIENT_RMs
FROM (
    SELECT FACT_ID,
        LISTAGG(CASE WHEN PROMISE_QTY < REQUEST_QTY THEN RM_ITEM_NAME END, ', ')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RM_ID)  INSUFFICIENT_RMs,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN PROMISE_QTY < REQUEST_QTY   THEN RM_ITEM_NAME END) INSUFFICIENT_cnt
    FROM MY_RMDETAILS
    GROUP BY FACT_ID
) t1 INNER JOIN MY_FACT t2
ON t1.FACT_ID = t2.FACT_ID
```